# How do i manage multiple tabs in tab accordion using Bootstrap and html

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have used vertical tab accordion in the bootstrap of col-sm-6. Now the problem is i can show only three tabs in my code, if i am adding more it goes in the new row and it looks so bad. Can I manage multiple tabs just like google chrome multiple tab system?

Here is the Link:
http://128.199.133.48/new/index1.php

Comment: Please provide working code example.

Comment: provide your code please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a bootstrap tab with scroll in case you have multiple tabs and dont want the new tab to come in new row, here is the link [plinkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iMJ435SFXjIX18YEM4Z4?p=preview)

```
 <script src="jquery.scrolling-tabs.js"></script>
```